# Regex to check consecutive occurrence of period symbol in username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have to validate username in my app so that it cannot contain two consecutive period symbols. I tried the following.

```
 username.match(/(..)/)
```

but found out that this matches "a." and "a..". I expected to get nil as the output of the match operation for input "a.". Is my approach right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put a \ in front of the periods, because period is a reserved character for "any character except newline".

So try:

```
username.match(/(\.\.)/)
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Short answer

You can use something like this ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/4yvpp8SeVk)):

```
username.match(/\.{2}/)
```

The `.` is escaped by preceding with a backslash, `{2}` is exact repetition specifier, and the brackets are removed since capturing is not required in this case.

---

#### On metacharacters and escaping

The dot, as a pattern metacharacter, matches (almost) any character. To match a literal period, you have at least two options:

- Escape the dot as `\.`
- Match it as a character class singleton `[.]`

Other metacharacters that may need escaping are `|` (alternation), `+`/`*`/`?`/`{`/`}` (repetition), `[`/`]` (character class), `^`/`$` (anchors), `(`/`)` (grouping), and of course `\` itself.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Literals and metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), [Dot: `.`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [Character Class: `[…]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors: `^$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition: `*+?{…}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Alternation: `|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [Optional: `?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), [Grouping: `(…)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### On finite repetition

To match two literal periods, you can use e.g. `\.\.` or `[.][.]`, i.e. a simple concatenation. You can also use the repetition construct, e.g. `\.{2}` or [`[.]{2}`](http://www.rubular.com/r/4yvpp8SeVk).

The finite repetition specifier also allows you write something like [`x{3,5}` to match at least 3 but at most 5 `x`](http://www.rubular.com/r/zxT0zpi8Fb).

Note that repetition has a higher precedence that concatenation, so `ha{3}` doesn't match `"hahaha"`; [it matches `"haaa"` instead](http://www.rubular.com/r/rmFqVVMgWQ). You can use grouping like [`(ha){3}` to match `"hahaha"`](http://www.rubular.com/r/WqUstCb7Gw).

---

#### On grouping

Grouping `(…)` captures the string it matches, which can be useful when you want to capture a match made by a subpattern, or if you want to use it as a backreference in the other parts of the pattern.

If you don't need this functionality, then a non-capturing option is `(?:…)`. Thus something like [`(?:ha){3}` still matches `"hahaha"`](http://www.rubular.com/r/WqUstCb7Gw) like before, but without creating a capturing group.

If you don't actually need the grouping aspect, then you can just leave out the brackets altogether.